# swapping values between two multi select boxes in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

[image]
How to select the first element in select box a, if I am at last position. if I am in middle of the list I am able to select but not able to select the first item in list if my current position is last.

```
function MoveSelected(objSourceElement, objTargetElement)
    {
        var aryTempSourceOptions = new Array();
        var x = 0;
        var y = 0; 
        //looping through source element to find selected options
        for (var i = 0; i < objSourceElement.length; i++) {
            if (objSourceElement.options[i].selected) {
                y++;
                //need to move this option to target element
                var intTargetLen = objTargetElement.length++;
                objTargetElement.options[intTargetLen].text = objSourceElement.options[i].text;
                objTargetElement.options[intTargetLen].value = objSourceElement.options[i].value;
            }
           else {
                //storing options that stay to recreate select element
                var objTempValues = new Object();
                objTempValues.text = objSourceElement.options[i].text;
                objTempValues.value = objSourceElement.options[i].value;
                aryTempSourceOptions[x] = objTempValues;
                x++;                    
            }               
        }       
        if (y==0) alert("Please select any Course");
        //resetting length of source
        objSourceElement.length = aryTempSourceOptions.length;
        //looping through temp array to recreate source select element
        for (var i = 0; i < aryTempSourceOptions.length; i++) {
            objSourceElement.options[i].text = aryTempSourceOptions[i].text;
            objSourceElement.options[i].value = aryTempSourceOptions[i].value;
           //objSourceElement.options[i].selected = false;
        } 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm late to this party but I have code that swaps selected values between two containers, taking care to keep track of option groups if they exist:

```
function MoveSelectedItems(source, destination)
{

var sourceElement = document.getElementById(source);

var destinationElement = document.getElementById(destination);

var toSource = {};
var toDestination = {};

// Move all children from our destination element into our toDestination
// dicationary.  This will be used to make sure groups are properly populated
// between source and destination
while (destinationElement.firstChild)
{
    var child = destinationElement.firstChild;
    destinationElement.removeChild(child);
    toDestination[child.label] = child;
}

// Loop through all the children of our source and move them to toDestination if
// they're selected and to toSource if not.  Also creates options groups as necessary
while (sourceElement.firstChild)
{
    var outerChild = sourceElement.firstChild;
    sourceElement.removeChild(outerChild)

    // If the current outerChild is an option group...
    if (outerChild.nodeName == 'OPTGROUP')
    {
        // Loop through the children of the current option group outer child
        while (outerChild.firstChild)
        {
            var innerChild = outerChild.firstChild;
            outerChild.removeChild(innerChild);

            // If the child of the option group is selected...
            if (innerChild.selected == true)
            {
                // If the option group isn't already in the destination dictionary
                // add it using the label of the outer child as the key
                if (!(outerChild.label in toDestination))
                {
                    toDestination[outerChild.label] = document.createElement('optgroup');
                    toDestination[outerChild.label].label = outerChild.label;
                }

                innerChild.selected = false;

                // Add the inner child to it's parent group in the destination dictionary
                toDestination[outerChild.label].appendChild(innerChild);
            }
            else  // If the child of the option group isn't selected...
            {
                // If the option group isn't already in the source ditionary
                // add it using the label of the outer child as the key
                if (!(outerChild.label in toSource))
                {
                    toSource[outerChild.label] = document.createElement('optgroup');
                    toSource[outerChild.label].label = outerChild.label;
                }

                innerChild.selected = false;

                // Add the inner child to it's parent group in the source dictionary
                toSource[outerChild.label].appendChild(innerChild);
            }
        }
    }
    else if (outerChild.nodeName == 'OPTION') // If the outer child is an option...
    {
        // If the outer child is selected, add it to the destination
        // dictionary using its label as the key.
        // Otherwise, if the the outer child is not selected, add it to
        // the source dictionary using it's label as the key.
        if (outerChild.selected == true)
        {
            outerChild.selected = false;

            toDestination[outerChild.label] = outerChild;
        }
        else
        {
            toSource[outerChild.label] = outerChild;
        }
    }
}

// Loop through the elements in toSource, sort them and append them to
// the Source element
for (var i in toSource)
{
    sourceElement.appendChild(toSource[i]);
}

// Loop through the elements in toDestination, sort them and append them to
// the Destination element
for (var i in toDestination)
{
    destinationElement.appendChild(toDestination[i]);
}
```

}

Answer (score -1):

**Java Script Function :**

```
function listbox_move(listID, direction) {
var listbox = document.getElementById(listID);
var selIndex = listbox.selectedIndex;
if (-1 == selIndex) {
    alert("Please select an option to move.");
    return;
}
var increment = -1;
if (direction == 'up')
    increment = -1;
else
    increment = 1; if ((selIndex + increment) < 0 || (selIndex + increment) > (listbox.options.length - 1)) {
    return;
}
var selValue = listbox.options[selIndex].value;
var selText = listbox.options[selIndex].text;
listbox.options[selIndex].value = listbox.options[selIndex + increment].value
listbox.options[selIndex].text = listbox.options[selIndex + increment].text
listbox.options[selIndex + increment].value = selValue;
listbox.options[selIndex + increment].text = selText;
listbox.selectedIndex = selIndex + increment;
}

function listbox_moveacross(sourceID, destID) {
var src = document.getElementById(sourceID);
var dest = document.getElementById(destID);
for (var count = 0; count < src.options.length; count++) {
    if (src.options[count].selected == true) {
        var option = src.options[count];
        var newOption = document.createElement("option");
        newOption.value = option.value;
        newOption.text = option.text;
        newOption.selected = true;
        try {
            dest.add(newOption, null);
            src.remove(count, null);
        } catch (error) {
            dest.add(newOption);
            src.remove(count);
        }
        count--;
    }
}
}

function listbox_selectall(listID, isSelect) {
var listbox = document.getElementById(listID);
for (var count = 0; count < listbox.options.length; count++) {
    listbox.options[count].selected = isSelect;
}
}
```

**HTML Code :**

```
<table>
<tr valign="top">
    <td>
        <SELECT id="s" size="10" multiple>
            <OPTION value="a">Afghanistan</OPTION>
            <OPTION value="b">Bahamas</OPTION>
            <OPTION value="c">Barbados</OPTION>
            <OPTION value="d">Belgium</OPTION>
            <OPTION value="e">Bhutan</OPTION>
            <OPTION value="f">China</OPTION>
            <OPTION value="g">Croatia</OPTION>
            <OPTION value="h">Denmark</OPTION>
            <OPTION value="i">France</OPTION>
        </SELECT>
    </td>
    <td valign="center">
        <a href="#" onclick="listbox_moveacross('s', 'd')">&gt;&gt;</a>
        <br/>
        <a href="#" onclick="listbox_moveacross('d', 's')">&lt;&lt;</a>
    </td>
    <td>
        <SELECT id="d" size="10" multiple>
            <OPTION value="a">Afghanistan</OPTION>
            <OPTION value="b">Bahamas</OPTION>
            <OPTION value="c">Barbados</OPTION>
            <OPTION value="d">Belgium</OPTION>
            <OPTION value="e">Bhutan</OPTION>
            <OPTION value="f">China</OPTION>
            <OPTION value="g">Croatia</OPTION>
            <OPTION value="h">Denmark</OPTION>
            <OPTION value="i">France</OPTION>
        </SELECT>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Web pages, and especially blogs, come and go. You should paste in the code or procedure that you feel answered the question so that this doesn't become an answer with only a dead link.

Comment: Its not a correct answer brother anyhow thank you for your replay.and i don't want to highlight selected item i want to highlight next item in the list once its reached its end point if we have any items left before last element next first item should be highlight.